# StructureMap - Inject Conditional Class

Tags: conditional-statements, structuremap

I have 1 interface named IProcessor having multiple implementations like ABCProcessor, PQRProcessor.
I want to make use of specific processor based on external parameters. How can I achive the same using StructureMap.

I am looking at named instances for the same.

Comment: What are these "external parameters"?

Comment: External Parameters are like configuration keys which drives the selection of processor.

Comment: You don't need anything conditional when the value is constant. Configuration values don't change during the lifetime of the app so you can simply configure sreucturemap unconditionally based on those values.

Comment: no, value is not constant. My exe will receive a client name from external world & i want to inject specific processor for that specific client.

Comment: In that case the answer is to implement a proxy class that implements IProcessor and wraps both ABCProcessor and PQRProcessor.

Comment: Hi Steve, can you elaborate a little please..

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here's my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a factory pattern:

```cs
public interface IProcessorFactory
{
    IProcessor Create(int dropDownValue);
}

public class ProcessorFactory : IProcessorFactory
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;
    public ProcessorFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IProcessor Create()
    {
        if(//your condition)
            return _container.GetInstance<ABCProcessor>();

        _container.GetInstance<PQRProcessor>();
    }
}
```

(or simply inject the required dependencies instead of the container)
and then simply

```cs
private readonly IProcessorFactory _processorFactory;

public MvcController(IProcessorFactory processorFactory)
{
    _processorFactory = processorFactory;
}

public void Method()
{
    var processor = _processorFactory.Create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your problem is to hide the knowledge of the existence of multiple implementations and the selection between them from the consumer by implementing a proxy implementation for `IProcessor`:

```
public sealed ProxyProcessor : IProcessor
{
    private readonly ABCProcessor abc;
    private readonly PQRProcessor pqr;
    private readonly IProcessorConfig config;

    public ProxyProcessor(ABCProcessor abc, PQRProcessor pqr, IProcessorConfig config) {
        this.abc = abc;
        this.pqr = pqr;
        this.config = config;
    }

    // Implement IProcessor methods to forward to the CurrentProcessor.
    public void Process() => CurrentProcessor.Process();

    private IProcessor CurrentProcessor => config.ProcessorType == "ABC" ? abc : pqr;
}
```

By doing this you can delegate to the correct implementation at runtime **while the consumer stays oblivious** to the fact that you make a decision at runtime about this. Now instead of injecting either an `ABCProcessor` or `PQRProcessor` into the consumers, you now inject a `ProxyProcessor` into the consumers. For instance, this is how the object graph for the `ProxyProcessor` could look like:

```
IProcessor processor =
    new ProxyProcessor(
        abc: new ABCProcessor(), 
        pqr: new PQRProcessor(), 
        config: new SqlProcessorConfig("constr"));
```

Note that this solution has several benefits over the use of a factory, such as:

- It prevents having to make any changes to the consumers; the consumers stay oblivious.
- It prevents introducing unneeded complexity into the consumers; with the factory approach, consumers have to deal with with an extra dependency. This complicates code and tests.
- It causes object graphs to be constructed in a delayed fashion, which complicates verification of object graphs.

Please read [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100) if you want to know more about why factories hardly ever are the right abstraction.